# Law of large numbers with random index more detailed proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

The question I'm interested in has been asked here
[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132702/law-of-large-numbers-with-random-index#*=*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132702/law-of-large-numbers-with-random-index#_=_)

But the proof is lacking in details. Can someone give a more rigorous argument or provide a citation for the steps taken?

Comment: Consider two events $A=\{S_n/n\to\mathbb{E}[X]\}$ and $B=\{I_n\to\infty\}$. Then $A\cap B$ has full probability, and for each $\omega\in A\cap B$ the sequence $(S_{I_n(\omega)}(\omega)/I_n(\omega))_{n\geq1}$ is a subsequence of $(S_n(\omega)/n)_{n\geq1}$ which converges to $\mathbb{E}[X]$, hence itself converges to th same value.

Comment: So the fact that $S_{I_n}$ and $I_n$ are not independent doesn't effect anything?

Comment: No, it does not affect anything because the argument is no different from the deterministic case. Inceed, once you fix a sample $\omega$ from $A\cap B$, the argument is now completely deterministic because both $(S_n(\omega)/n)_{n\geq1}$ and $(I_N(\omega))_{n\geq 1}$ are just sequences in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What does this notation $I_n(w)$ mean is it $I_n$ conditioned on $w$?

Comment: Recall that a random variable is a function from the sample space $\Omega$ (which we often sweep under the rug) to $\mathbb{R}$. So $I_N(\omega)$ is simply the function notation indicating the value of $I_N$ evaluated at $\omega$.

Comment: Why does a subsequence converge to the same value sequence? Couldnt the sub sequence not converge? Sorry this isnt really my area, do you think I could find this in a textbook?

Comment: This is a standard exercise in real analysis which is readily proved from the $\epsilon$-$N$ definition of limit. But the intuition is very clear: For a sequence $(a_n)$ of real numbers and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, the statement $\lim a_n = \alpha$ means that $a_n$ is close to $\alpha$ for any large index $n$ (with the 'closeness' improving as we ignore as many leading terms as we please). Then it is clear that the same will happen for any subsequence of $(a_n)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97015/discussion-between-tpaul-and-sangchul-lee).